# common interface for RemoteWebDriver and WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc

I have two methods:
1. Receives `RemoteWebDriver` object and performs `findElement()` on it.
2. Receives `WebElement` object and performs `findElement()`on it.

Is there a way to unite these two into a single method that receives either `RemoteWebDriver` or `WebElement` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common interface is `SearchContext`:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html

(your IDE is able to give you such information, look for the type hierarchy)